# Passing pointer to member func of outer class template to nested class

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I'm having difficulty passing a pointer to the member function `Outer<T>::foo` to the constructor of the nested class `Outer` as shown below (see also [ideone](http://ideone.com/e1LAwg)).

```
template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    void foo()
    {
    }

    Outer() : inner( &Outer::foo )  // ERROR: compiles without &Outer::foo and Inner( F f ), below
    {
    }

    template<typename T2, void (T2::*F)()>
    struct Inner
    {
        Inner( F f )    // ERROR
        {
        }
    };

    Inner<Outer,&Outer::foo> inner;
};

int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've begun to wonder if this is at all possible.

Comment: Aren't you referring to Outer::foo, without taking into account the expanded version. The compiler doesn't yet know what specific function pointer to grab while it is trying to instantiate the template itself!

Comment: `F` is not a type, it's a function pointer. Why are you passing a parameter if you already know what the object is?

Comment: sorry, I don't see any nested classes...

Comment: @Bot Huh? `Outer<T1>::Inner` is a nested template type.

Comment: still don't see any classes only structs and templates

Comment: @Bot The only difference between a class and a struct is default member visibility. There isn't a good reason to distinguish them in this context.

Comment: not going argue difference between struct and class. Well if it suits the context then who cares about the differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are conflating variables and template arguments.  You can use constant pointers as template arguments, or you can pass variable pointers as arguments to functions.

This works:

```
template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    void foo()
    {
    }

    Outer() : inner( &Outer::foo ) 
    {
    }

    template<typename T2>
    struct Inner
    {
        // Takes a pointer at runtime to any matching signature in T2
        Inner( void (T2::*f)( ) ) 
        {
        }
    };

    Inner<Outer> inner;
};

int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b5d3299a4610e9f)

or this works:

```
template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    void foo()
    {
    }

    Outer() : inner( )  
    {
    }

    // Takes a pointer at compile time to a matching function in T2
    template<typename T2, void (T2::*f)()>
    struct Inner
    {
        Inner( )
        {
        }
    };

    Inner<Outer,&Outer::foo> inner;
};

int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/491625c895ac2b9c)

Comment: Massive thanks. Here's a version of your solution http://ideone.com/LyYZKG . Oddly, although private, I'm able to call `Outer<T>::foo()` from `Inner`. Does the standard allow this? BTW, I tested in MSVC 2013 and GCC 4.8.3

Comment: That's legit because it is `Outer` that actually passes the pointer.  Basically, the Outer class, who has rights to all of it's components, it choosing to pass the pointer to someone else.  Outside the class it is just a pointer and public/private are not checked.  If `Inner` tried to access `Outer<T>::foo()` directly it would be denied.

Comment: That's interesting Jay. Its quite similar like passing a reference to a private member outside. See my following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537482/able-to-use-pointer-to-function-to-call-private-method-of-an-external-class

Comment: A useful follow-up.  Thanks.