# Able to use pointer to function to call private method of an external class

Tags: c++, private, pointer-to-member

Based on the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536395/passing-pointer-to-member-func-of-outer-class-template-to-nested-class/27536576#27536576) to a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536395/passing-pointer-to-member-func-of-outer-class-template-to-nested-class), I'm able to use a function pointer in order to call the private method `Foo<T>::foo()` from another class `Bar`, as shown below (see also [ideone](http://ideone.com/IDsmgY))

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef void (T::*F)();

    Bar( T& t_ , F f ) : t( t_ ) , func( f )
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        (t.*func)();
    }

    F func;
    T& t;
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<T>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }

public:    
    Foo() : bar( *this , &Foo::foo ) 
    {
        bar();
    }

    Bar<Foo<T> > bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
}
```

This works on MSVC 2013 and GCC 4.8.3. Is it valid?

Comment: Sure, why shouldn't it be? Access was checked when the pointer was assigned.

Comment: This is really no different to going `public: void buz() { foo(); }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is permissible, and it works.

[C++ Programming by Bjarne Stroustoup](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CJw3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=Because%20C%2B%2B%20protects%20against%20accident%20rather%20than%20deliberate%20circumvention%20%28fraud%29&source=bl&ots=JghrbQgbsu&sig=8aQeG7YGyBRMXSOt20wb6byQyC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=diWSVNTvEcLj8AX20YLoBw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Because%20C%2B%2B%20protects%20against%20accident%20rather%20than%20deliberate%20circumvention%20(fraud)&f=false)

> C++ protects against accident rather than deliberate circumvention
>   (fraud)

Sure, you cannot directly/easily call private methods outside the class, but if you are making enough efforts, C++ will allow it.

Comment: There is no circumventing involved here, it's a straightforward use of a pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator circumventing against private data members.

Comment: @Deduplicator `(t.*func)();` -- circumvention, private member--> void foo(). I am missing something?

Comment: @Deduplicator You made `public` to `protected` member in derived class, OP called `private` from function. There is a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67170/discussion-between-pranit-kothari-and-deduplicator).

Comment: @PranitKothari `Foo` is the one forming a pointer to its private member function, which it's obviously allowed to do. All `Bar<Foo<T>>` knows is it was passed a pointer to member function that points to *something*, access control does not come into the picture at that point. You're simply invoking that *something* by calling `Bar::operator()`

Comment: @Praetorian I didn't say it is not allow. But calling `foo` like `(t.*func)();` , isn't calling to private member of other class?

Comment: Yes, but it's doing so only because it happened to be initialized with a pointer to a private member function. The OP seems confused about how access control works, and your answer implies he's doing something sneaky to circumvent access control, when there's no such thing going on.

Answer (score 20):

C++ standard says

> 11.1 A member of a class can be
>    (1.1) — private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.

i.e. the access specifier is applied to the name, not the executable code. This makes sense if you think about it, since access specifiers are a compile-time construct.

Comment: Yes, for the standard quote.

Comment: It should be noted that it is the choice of the class `Foo` to provide the constructor of `Bar` with the pointer to the function. Without this help from the inside, Bar would not be able to call `Foo::foo()` from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid.

`Bar.operator()()` is just using a pointer, not trying to use an identifier with private access specifier.
It does not matter how that pointer was initialized, as long as it points to the right function.

[As an example, look at this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/252eea2913d220d7):

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
protected:
    void hidden() { std::cout << "But I was hidden !?\n"; }
};
struct B : A {
    using A::hidden; // Making it public
};
int main() {
    B().hidden();
}
```

As an aside, don't use `std::endl` unless you really want to flush the stream, as that's expensive.
Normally `'\n'` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

It does matter.

Header File

```
class A;
typedef int (A::*handler)(int x);
struct handler_pair {
    int code,
    handler fn
}

class A {
...
private:
  int onGoober(int x);
  int onGomer(int x);
};
```

Source file

```
handler_pair handler_map[] = {
    {0, &A::onGoober},          // these will complain about the method being private
    {1, &A::onGomer}
};
```

Changing the handler_map to a static member in the class and initializing that way avoids the complaint.

Where you take the address of the member function is important.